# Organizing css for large sites

Tags: html, css

I have a more general design question relating to css and websites. I know that it is good computer science to normalize code as much as possible and avoid duplication. So it would stand to reason to me, at least in theory that one would do the same when organizing stylesheets for a website.

So when I started on my most recent website I started out with this same philosophy. It worked ok for my first few pages and while I was only testing in firefox...

However as my site grew and as I added pages, multiple layouts (and browsers) I found this philosophy broke down really quickly. Ultimately over time I have moved to the following approach:

1. I have a very limited top level css file for each master page layout in my site, it contains classes for well known styles across that layout as well as css for the master page.
2. I keep specific css styles for each page.
3. I keep specific css styles for embeddable page elements / controls

I ended up taking this route so that I could trust that changes on one page wouldn't accidentally break other pages in the site resulting in a lot of regression bugs.

What do other people do when approaching this? Is this a good / bad approach... I do see cons to this approach, some pages are very similar so making a significant change means changing more css code, I also feel that the pro's outweigh this on a daily basis.

What do other developers think about this philosophy? Good? Bad? Just curious really...

To me its one of those situations where I weighed the difference between my ideals (I try to keep very tight code), and the frustration of changing requirements on one page breaking 20 other pages because I changed a div width by a few pixels (upsetting a float on another page for instance).

Thanks for your input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like any other type of code, if you are duplicating your CSS code all over the place, you are asking for trouble. Maintenance is going to get harder and harder for you as time goes on.

The best way to not have issues with a change on one page affecting other pages detrimentally is to have a style guide that drives your UI layout and design. If your style guide defintes the HTML and CSS classes to use for a given design element, then they will all always be displayed the same across all pages. If a specific page's element needs to be changed, you change the HTML to use a different class and then build new CSS for that class (and add it to your style guide for reuse). The style guide also allows you to make sure that your HTML is uniform across all developers working on the site, which means even less of a chance of CSS changes causing problems as you do more development.

Another point you need to remember with CSS is that every one of those .css files you create and reference on a page is an HTTP request. If every page and control has its own CSS file, you are really hurting your users' experience on the site by bogging down the total request download time for every single page request. It also makes it less likely for their browser to cache the .css files because the cache has a limited amount of space, so if you keep filling it with more and more .css files, they are going to get dumped from the cache more quickly. Yes, you can combine .css files programmatically in a handler so your page only makes one request per page, but then you have additional server overhead and the caching issue still remains (unless you have a single request for all .css files on your site, which defeats the purpose of what you're trying to do here anyways).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on the performance cost to this. It's probably one I am willing to live with though. On the 1st point of maintenance getting harder and harder, personally I wonder whether it is that cut and dry. There are pros and cons to both. With the approach you suggest (which is how I started out), I found that every time css was edited, every page on the site needs to be regression tested (on every browser), so as you add pages your regression test matrix grows exponentially (multiplied by number of browsers) ... Thoughts?

Comment: +1 for mentioning a style guide. @Introgy, if you keep a HTML style guide with simple but complete examples of the content on your pages it will be easier to test in multiple browsers. If you are using CSS as it is intend, you shouldn't have to retest every page when a change is made.

Comment: + Thanks for all the help Charles. I have a lot less css now, I think where I was running into issues is I have a lot of very unique forms with layout on each one that was very specific to the task at hand. Thanks again